# OpenCV 3.0 : Failed to load OpenCL Runtime

Tags: python, opencv, installation, runtime, opencl

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and I just installed OpenCV 3.0.
I previously had OpenCV 2.4.9 and that worked perfectly.
I tried installing OpenCL using the following code:

```
sudo apt-get install ocl-icd-opencl-dev
```

But got the following error

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ocl-icd-opencl-dev
```

So what should I do?

Comment: Perhaps the package you want is libopencv-ocl-dev or libopencv-gpu-dev?

Comment: @mdurant How do I get libopencv-ocl-dev?

Comment: This is it in 13.10; you'll have to dig the history to see if earlier versions had different names: http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/libopencv-ocl-dev

Comment: I would try this first http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/libopencv-gpu-dev

Comment: I searched my system using Synaptic package manager and it showed that libopencv-gpu-dev was already installed.

Answer (score 0):

This is the command that you need:

```
sudo apt-get install opencl-dev
```